# Java log4j Configuration file doesn't work

Tags: java, log4j

I have a log4j configuration file as below, what I want to do is output the TRACE in the console and output the ERROR message to the file (fileerror). But it doesn't work, both the console and file is at the TRACE level.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
  xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="fileerror" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="1024MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="2" />
        <param name="file" value="ExonImpact.error.log.txt" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="ccbb.hrbeu" additivity="true">
            <level value="TRACE"/>
            <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </logger>
    <root>
            <level value="ERROR"/>
            <appender-ref ref="fileerror" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Below is my log4j debug information.

```
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [ccbb.hrbeu] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for ccbb.hrbeu is  [TRACE].
log4j: ccbb.hrbeu level set to TRACE
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [console] to category [ccbb.hrbeu].
log4j: Level value for root is  [ERROR].
log4j: root level set to ERROR
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender]
log4j: Setting property [append] to [false].
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [1024MB].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [2].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [ExonImpact.error.log.txt].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: setFile called: ExonImpact.error.log.txt, false
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Adding appender named [fileerror] to category [root].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, all messages caught by a child logger are propagated to the root logger. That's why both of your loggers log the same message. You can set your additivity parameter to false (additivity="false") to prevent your logger from passing messages to the root logger. Or you can add an additional "threshold" parameter to your  file appender:

```
<param name="Threshold" value="ERROR" />
```

then it will ignore all messages below Error level.